# show/hide div with id specified in input form

Tags: jquery, html, textarea, containers

I got a lot of divs on page with ids like these:

```
<div id="s001">, <div id="s002">, <div id="s003">....<div id="s050">...<div id="s200">
```

By default all these divs are hidden.
There is text input form. User types something like `s005` in textarea and div with id=`s005` appear. If the next input is `s101` — only div `s101` becomes visible and div `s005` is hidden again. If input is there is no div with id specified in textarea — we just dislay nothing.

So I need to apply and remove classes from my divs, but I'm not sure how — with addClass or toggleClass 
I am pretty new to jQuery, but I did research for this case and come up with these:

head:

```
<style type="text/css">
            .hidden { display: none }
            .shown { display: block }
</style>
```

body:

```
<input type="text" size="4">
<script>
    $("input").keyup(function () {
      var value = $(this).val();
      $(#value).toggleClass("shown", addOrRemove);            
    }).keyup();
</script>

<div id="s001" class="hidden">s001 contents</div>
<div id="s002" class="hidden">s002 contents</div>
<div id="s003" class="hidden">s003 contents</div>
<div id="s004" class="hidden">s004 contents</div>
<div id="s005" class="hidden">s005 contents</div>
```

I am sure that this string is wrong:

```
$(#value).toggleClass("shown", addOrRemove);
```

But I have no idea what should I change. I believe that the main comlication is that class `shown` must be removed after text in input form is changed. Only one div must be displayed at one time!
thanks everyone in advance and sorry for being noob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example that is working. The only thing that is not happening is the call to the function 'addOrRemove'.

http://jsfiddle.net/pVEus/

Hope this gets you started.

Bob

Comment: And here is one that includes the 'addOrRemove' function. http://jsfiddle.net/pVEus/3/

Comment: addOrRemove is not a function (I thought so at first too) -- the second parameter of the toggleClass function allows you to pass true/false as to whether the class should be added or removed. He copied/pasted from the jQuery examples where they used a variable of that name.

Comment: awesome!! version 2 works just like I wanted! I appreciate your help very much! thank you!

Comment: so I see "addOrRemove" is not needed here, right? patmortech, you are right, I tried to find answer to my question in jQuery examples, but obviously I failed.

Comment: Bob, unfortunately I have no right to vote yet. But you can be sure that you made my day!

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#"+value).toggleClass("shown", addOrRemove);
```

Should do the trick

Comment: Unfortinately it does not.. Should I change someting else in this code? I believe that classes must be switched — `shown` or `hidden`, but have no idea how to make it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following (notice I also gave your textbox an id so this doesn't blow up when you have other textboxes on the screen):

```
<input type="text" id="idToShow" size="4">
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#idToShow").keyup(function () {

      //hide the currently shown div
      $('div.shown').removeClass('shown').addClass('hidden');

      //show the div with id entered in textbox
      var value = $(this).val();
      $('#' + value).removeClass('hidden').addClass('shown');

    }).keyup();
}
</script>
```

Comment: somehow it doesn't work. checked and rechecked - still doesn't work. have no idea.

Comment: Probably didn't work because it wasn't in $(document).ready(). I was only focused on the script itself, so forgot to do that. I have added it in above for completeness. This does work. Make sure to set the id for the text box correctly.